# how can i repeat a string multiple times according to its index in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to write a function with a string as a parameter,
and the output should be the same string with each character repeated as many times as the character's index, with capitalizing the first letter.

For example, function `accum(abc)` should return: `A-Bb-Ccc`

`accum(zytx)` should return: `Z-Yy-Ttt-Xxxx`

I tried the following code but it is not working. Can someone help me out?

```js
function accum(s) {
  var strSplit = s.toLowerCase().split('');

  var newArr = strSplit.map((element, i) => 
  element.repeat(i+1).charAt(0).toUpperCase()+element.substr(1));

  console.log("the new Arr is: "+newArr.join('-'));
  return newArr.join('-');
}

accum("abcd");
```

Comment: Btw, your specification only works if array indexes are 1-based. If they are 0-based, the first character would always be mapped to the empty string (i.e. repeated 0 times). E.g. `accum('abc') === '-B-CC'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In functional style (thanks to @Redu for the comment):

```js
const accum = (s) => Array.from(
    s,
    (c, i) => `${c.toLocaleUpperCase()}${c.repeat(i)}`
  )
  .join('-');

console.log(accum(''));
console.log(accum('a'));
console.log(accum('xyz'));
```

Your code doesn't work because in this line

```
element.repeat(i+1).charAt(0).toUpperCase()+element.substr(1))
```

`element.substr(1)` tries to get the substring starting at index 1 of a single character (which is always the empty string). You probably thought that `element.repeat(i+1)` would work **in place** (i.e. modify `element`) whereas it returns a new string (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)).

You can fix this as follows:

```js
function accum(s) {
  var strSplit = s.toLowerCase().split('');

  var newArr = strSplit.map((element, i) => 
  `${element.toLocaleUpperCase()}${element.repeat(i)}`);

  console.log("the new Arr is: "+newArr.join('-'));
  return newArr.join('-');
}

accum("abcd");
```

Comment: This is nice.. But just as a reminder, `Array.from()` already takes a mapping callback. So you may simplify your code to `var accum = s => Array.from(s, (c,i) => c.toLocaleUpperCase() + c.repeat(i)).join('-');`

Comment: @Redu Thanks, didn't know that!

Comment: Literal no need for `.charAt(0)`. `element` is already going to be a single character.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `.charAt(0)` which is always taking the first character, and you're not repeating the lowercase letters afterwards.

```js
function accum(s) {

  var strSplit = s.toLowerCase().split('');

  var newArr = strSplit.map(
    (element, i) => element.toUpperCase()+element.repeat(i));

  return newArr.join('-');
}

console.log("the new Arr is:", accum("abcd"));
console.log("zytx:", accum("zytx"));
```

You can simplify this even further, by removing the `.substr()` and just put `element.repeat(i)`. On the first iteration, `i` will be 0 and return an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using a simple regex and `repeat` too, as in:

```js
function accum(s) {
  var i = 0;

  return s.replace(/./g, m => "-" + m.toUpperCase() + m.repeat(i++)).slice(1);
}

console.log(accum("abcd"));
```

The `slice(1)` part is used to remove the `-` from the start of the string.